# RxJs: Calculating observable array length in component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable array, `purchases$`.  In my angular 2 component I'd like to calculate the length of the array.  I worry that the observable is never complete and thus my subscriptions end up piling up.  If I do the following will the subscription be complete?

```
this.purchases$.subscribe((val) => {
  val.length > 0 ? this.purchaseType = 'initial' : this.purchaseType = 'additional'
})
```

Once I have an initial value I am happy to unsubscribe.

Can I simple add `.unsubscribe()` to the end?

Comment: you can also use `takeWhile` operator, use it with a variable that get to false on the `onDestroy`, so your subscription will be deleted once the component will be desotryed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your subscriptions doesn't affect the source Observable so if you want to unsubscribe you need to use an operator that completes the chain or unsubscribe manually.

For example if you know how many items you want to accept you can use `take(N)` or if it depends on a certain condition you can use `takeWhile()`. Or you can collect items with `scan()` and combine it with `takeWhile()` for example.

You can also unsubscribe right in your subscribe call:

```
this.purchases$.subscribe(function(val) {
  if (condition) {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }
});
```

Note that in this case you can't use arrow functions `() => ...` because RxJS binds `this` context to the current `Subscription` object. That's why you can call `this.unsubscribe()` and unsubscribe (this is not a hack, it's intended to be used this way).

Comment: where would I include the `take(N)` in my subscription?

Comment: `this.purchases$.pipe(take(N)).subscribe(...)`

Comment: seems like angular isn't recognizing `pipe`... hmmm

Answer (score 1):

Rather than imperatively unsubscribing, i'd recommend you use the [first operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) to make an observable that automatically completes after the first result is emitted:

```
this.purchases$.pipe(first()).subscribe((val) => {
  val.length > 0 ? this.purchaseType = 'initial' : this.purchaseType = 'additiona';
})
```